# How to download the latest UniversalPackage with View name only in AzureDevops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops

How to download the latest UniversalPackage in AzureDevops with View only?

I checked azure yaml tasks, az CLI and cannot find appropriate rest interface
Is there any way to do it problematically like below?

```
  - task: UniversalPackages@0
    inputs:
      command: 'download'
      vstsFeed: 'myFeed'
      vstsFeedPackage: 'myPackage'
      vstsPackageVersion: '@MY_VIEW'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just need to specify the view in feedname, for example:

release view:

```
 steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal download'
  inputs:
    vstsFeed: 'Universalfeed@Release'
    vstsFeedPackage: helloworld
    vstsPackageVersion: '*'
```

CLI:

```
az artifacts universal download
    --organization https://dev.azure.com/xx/
    --feed Universalfeed@Release
    --name helloworld
    --version *
    --path .
```